# Dart Angular 2 and Material Design Components

Tags: dart, material-design, angular-material, angular-dart

We have Angular 2 for Dart:

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/README.md#the-goal-of-angular-material

Are there Material Design componentes to Angular 2 for Dart too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! The AngularDart Components (https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components) use material design. Here's a code lab to help you get familiar with these components (more docs to come):

https://webdev.dartlang.org/codelabs/angular2_components

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to edit sources of library, it doesn't matter, what language was used to create it, you can just use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular2_material